# WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

We are trying to build a flaskapp by following the instructions of [PythonProgramming](https://pythonprogramming.net/creating-first-flask-web-app/).

Please find the folder structure below.

```
username@server:/var/www/FlaskApp$ pwd
/var/www/FlaskApp
username@server:/var/www/FlaskApp$ ls
FlaskApp  flaskapp.wsgi

username@server:/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp$ pwd
/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp
username@server:/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp$ ls
__init__.py  static  templates  xlogin.py
```

Content of flaskapp.wsgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Thisissupposedtobesecret!'
```

Content of "/etc/apache2/sites-available/FlaskApp.conf"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName <server IP>
    ServerAdmin <email>
    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-path=/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi process-group=myapp application-group=%{GLOBAL}
    <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp>
    <Files flaskapp.wsgi>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Files>
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
    <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

When the app is run directly with python2 or python3, it is running fine.

```
username@server:/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp$ python3 __init__.py
/home/raj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:794: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
/home/raj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:794: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 231-825-237

username@server:/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp$ python __init__.py
/home/raj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:794: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
/home/raj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:794: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 151-229-561
```

But, the application is not working on the server.Following errors are observed in the error.log of apache2 server.

```
[Fri Feb 02 10:12:27.803660 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 21512:tid 140205275080448] [remote 172.16.67.27:60575] mod_wsgi (pid=21512): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Feb 02 10:12:27.803874 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 21512:tid 140205275080448] [remote 172.16.67.27:60575] mod_wsgi (pid=21512): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'.
[Fri Feb 02 10:12:27.803990 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 21512:tid 140205275080448] [remote 172.16.67.27:60575] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Feb 02 10:12:27.804065 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 21512:tid 140205275080448] [remote 172.16.67.27:60575]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
[Fri Feb 02 10:12:27.804078 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 21512:tid 140205275080448] [remote 172.16.67.27:60575]     from FlaskApp import app as application
[Fri Feb 02 10:12:27.804109 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 21512:tid 140205275080448] [remote 172.16.67.27:60575] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'FlaskApp'
```

Using " libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3" version. I browsed many articles with related errors and couldn't find a solution. Could you please help with these errors.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Thisissupposedtobesecret!'
```

Try using:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Thisissupposedtobesecret!'
```

The path needs to be the parent of the `FlaskApp` package, not the package directory itself.